# if-else loop not looping c++ opencv visualstudio

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking to create a loop where the user has to enter some numbers in order to re-sale an image. The re-scaling works if the user enters what's within the limits but when they enter a number which is to big the code breaks.

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
float Sx = 0;
float Sy = 0;
float NewX;
float NewY;

Mat img, ScaledImg;
img = imread("C:/Jakob/tower.jpg");

do
{
    cout << "The current image size is: " << img.rows << "x" << img.cols << endl;
    cout << "First enter the new width for the image: ";
    cin >> NewX;
    cout << "Seond enter the new height for the image: ";
    cin >> NewY;
    if ((NewX >= 1) && (NewX <= 2000))
        if ((NewY >=1) && (NewY <= 2000))
        {
            Sx = (NewX/img.rows); 
            cout << "You entered " << NewX << " For Width" << endl; 
            Sy = (NewY/img.cols);
            cout << "You entered " << NewY << " For Height" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The number you entered does not match the requirements " << endl;
            cout << "Please start over " << endl;
        }   

}
while (NewX < 1 && NewX >= 2000 && NewY < 1 && NewY >= 2000);

cout << "Sx = " << Sx << endl;
cout << "Sy = " << Sy << endl;

resize(img, ScaledImg, Size(img.cols*Sx,img.rows*Sy));
imwrite("C:/Jakob/ScaledImage.jpg", ScaledImg);

cout << "Rows: " << ScaledImg.rows << " and Cols: " << ScaledImg.cols << endl;

imshow("Original", img);
imshow("Scaled Image", ScaledImg);
/*system("PAUSE");*/
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

The error i get after running this code is that Sx is being used without being initialized. This only happens if the number is not within the range of 1-2000

Comment: hey, you got rows and cols wrong. should be (NewX/img.cols); and  (NewY/img.rows);

Comment: Ah yea i can see that now :D Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize the declared variables in order to use them

so you need to initialize the variable `Sx` and `Sy` to avoid this error

Replace

```
float Sx;
float Sy;
```

with

```
float Sx=0;
float Sy=0;
```

you have a problem with your do while condition

change it to

```
while ((NewX < 1 || NewX >= 2000) && (NewY < 1 || NewY >= 2000));
```

Comment: Tried that when Ashalynd suggested it. Just creates a new problem. Why is it that i have to declare them? From my understanding they are getting declared inside the if statement. And the variables also work if the user types something between 1-2000. Then There is no problem. The problem only occurs when the number is outside of this range.

Comment: Now it runs the code without any problems. If i don't enter the right values i have to do it again. Thank you for that :) Now i just have to figure out why it doesn't print the else statement hehe

Answer (score 3):

True, because by default the variables in C++ are initialized with garbage.
Do something like:

```
float Sx = 0.0;
float Sy = 0.0;
```

This line:

```
resize(img, ScaledImg, Size(img.cols*Sx,img.rows*Sy));
```

will only work if Sx and Sy aren't 0 of course, so you have to initialize them to something that makes sense to you if your other params are beyond 2000 range.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It gave me a new error with some memory location problem.

Comment: It did work - it solved the first problem. Now you have another question, which we need to know the words in the "new error" to solve

Comment: Yes, you have to describe what you do further with Sx and Sy to get more help :)

Comment: In that case, it solved a problem i didn't know existed :) The new error is: Unhandled exception at at 0x76B84B32 in ImageScaling.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x005BB16C.

Comment: Post the code, it could be anything: reaching beyond the allocated memory, using a pointer to an object which wasn't initialized properly, etc. E.g. if Sx and Sy are used to allocate a rectangle array and they are both 0, you probably won't get a useful array.

Comment: Okay. I Updated my post to include everything now :)

Comment: The thing is. Sx and Sy are not supposed to be declared from the start. Sx and Sy are dependent on which size the new image should be. If the user wants his 800x600 image to be 400x300 the code calculates the values of Sx and Sy to be 0.5 and re-sizes the image to it becomes 400x300.

Comment: So what should you do if a user wants an image beyond 2000x2000? If the intention is to do nothing, then you should check your Sx and Sy variables: if they are still 0.0 then you didn't get a valid range from the user and shouldn't resize your array at all.

Comment: It works nows. Seems like the problem were my while condition

Comment: Yea. I know it doesn't make much sense to limit image scaling but that was the point. If the user tried to get a image above 2000x2000 it should tell him that, that's not possible and to enter the new values within the range i told him to :)